# Align an element to the bottom of a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how I can align an element to the bottom of a div in CSS.

Here is a screenshot of my page: http://prntscr.com/5ivlm8 (The arrow is to show where I want the element to go)

And here is my page:

```
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
<div class="wrap">
   <div id="base">
       <div class="infobox">
           <div class="title">
               Welcome to <?php echo NOM_SITE; ?>
           </div>
           <div class="time">Today is <?php echo date("d/m/Y") ?></div>
       </div>
       <div class="enter">
          Test
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the "Enter" div CSS:

```
#base .enter {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#base` element needs to be positioned. Use `position: relative` on #base (absolute or fixed will also work).

Answer (score 1):

Here you will have to set the position of div with id=base to relative so that the enter div can adjust itself with it at the bottom left. Just include the below to your css

```
#base
{
    position: relative;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a Position:relative on #base(parent) it controls the .enter(child div) with in parent div,

css:

```
#base{
position:relative;}
#base .enter{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#base{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.enter{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
top:100%;
left:0;
}
```